# Sending a request over Tor without binding port on localhost

Tags: linux, socks, client

Usually, Tor works like that: a daemon starts in background, reads `torrc` and listens on `SocksPort` (usually 9050). Then an application uses `localhost:9050` as a SOCKS5 proxy and performs requests over Tor that way.

What I want to do is to perform a request over the Tor network on GNU/Linux without starting localhost proxy. *Something like* `torify curl`*, but without SOCKS5 proxies*. So is there a way to **send a request over Tor without using local proxy?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on using the standard tor implementation, then yes you will need to use some form of local proxy. If you don't want to bind the SOCKS port to a localhost address, you can also use a unix domain socket instead. For example using `SocksPort unix:/home/user/tor-socks.unix`.

If you want to avoid using a local proxy, then you will need to build the Tor client into the application itself. I don't know of any Tor libraries that do this, but the python [torpy](https://pypi.org/project/torpy/) library might be a good start.